# Cohort analysis by weeknumber

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform a last year's cohort analysis by weeknumber

The output would be:

```
weeknumber session_count acq_count

37           5           3

43           2           2
```

...

MySql thus far:

```
SELECT WEEK(datetime) AS weeknumber, COUNT(*) AS session_count, 
   acquisition as acq_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE acquisition=1 ) 
FROM sessions WHERE `datetime` >= NOW()- INTERVAL 365 DAY 
GROUP BY weeknumber
```

Challenge: how to also get the count of rows matching acquisition=1 in the same sql query?

Thanks for your thoughts!
Fred

Comment: what do you mean with "a quisition as acq_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE acquisition=1 ) " .. i don't understand ,,

Comment: I want to count the number of records where acquisition = 1. so this section `acquisition as acq_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE acquisition=1 )` may be total bollocks :/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this query

```
SELECT WEEK(datetime) AS weeknumber, COUNT(*) AS session_count, 
   SUM(acquisition=1) as acq_count 
FROM sessions WHERE `datetime` >= NOW()- INTERVAL 365 DAY 
GROUP BY weeknumber
```